# Return TRUE or FALSE for SUMPRODUCT

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, sumproduct

I have a formula that checks a date in plain text on another sheet with the date entered for a timesheet to see if it's a holiday or not.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(TEXT($A4,"mmm"),3)=LEFT(HOLIDAYS!$B$7:$B,3))*(DAY($A4)=--RIGHT(HOLIDAYS!$B$7:$B,2)))
```

However, the result of this formula is returning a 1 or 0.  I can work with the result in this form, I was just wondering is there any way I can make this formula return a TRUE or FALSE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to end of the formula `=1`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(TEXT($A4,"mmm"),3)=LEFT(HOLIDAYS!$B$7:$B,3))*(DAY($A4)=--RIGHT(HOLIDAYS!$B$7:$B,2)))=1
```

Comment: Well that was easy lol, I was trying to add ```,"true","false"``` in various places

Answer (score 1):

or try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(TEXT($A4, "mmm"), 3)=
 LEFT(HOLIDAYS!$B$7:$B, 3))*(DAY($A4)=N(RIGHT(HOLIDAYS!$B$7:$B, 2)))=1, TRUE))
```